# Makefile - compile C files separately

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, gnu-make

My folder structure is something like this:

```
build
ch01
  foo.c
  bar.c
ch02
  baz.c
  meow.c
```

Where every file is a separate program that has to be put into the subfolder with the same name in the `build/` directory (the whole build is in `.gitignore`)

```
build
  ch01
    foo, bar
  ch02
    baz, meow
```

Currently I have this Makefile doing what I need, but I don't like it.

```
CC   = gcc
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall -Wextra -ansi
SRCS   = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS  = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRCS))
MD   = mkdir
BINPREFIX = ../build
BUILD_DIR = $(BINPREFIX)/$(shell basename $(CURDIR))

all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): %.o: %.c
 @test -d $(BUILD_DIR) || $(MD) -p $(BUILD_DIR)
 $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
 $(CC) $@ -o $(patsubst %.o,$(BUILD_DIR)/%,$@)
 rm $@


clean:
 rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

There are two problems.

1. I have to split compilation/linking phases with manual removal of the object files because I can't provide the better solution to restore source file name out of the full build path.
2. I want to have separate target for the directory creation, but standard recommendation doesn't work:

```
all: $(OBJS) | $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BUILD_DIR):
  $(MD) -p $@
```

It simply doesn't run the `$(BUILD_DIR)` target.

Comment: You put `$(BUILD_DIR)` as a dependency of `all``, but you should put it to `$(OBJS):`, since there the build directory should exist when it is run. And where do you put the Makefile, into each ch01 and ch02 directory?

Comment: @ssbssa, yes, every folder has similar Makefile as they can have slightly different build options. Will try to change dependency, great.

Comment: This sort of thing is probably easier with a VPATH build.  eg, create build/ch01/Makefile that just contains two lines: `VPATH: ../../ch01` and `all: foo bar`  Let the default rules work.  Define CC, CFLAGS etc. in a top level Makefile that calls make recursively in the sub directories.

Comment: @WilliamPursell my goal for now is to get a new program built with the same settings as any other in the current directory without modifying Makefile at all. But I will look into VPATH, never heard about it. C and make is a very new thing to me :)

Comment: VPATH builds can be powerful, but...you're reinventing the wheel.  As soon as your build gets sufficiently complicated, you probably want to start doing some research into more complete build systems.  Make is great for toys and simple projects, but you are probably already at the point where you should look into something more complete (eg, bazel, cmake, autotools, scons, etc.). I recommend you not bother trying to make this work with make; just build the object files and executables in the directory with the sources.  When that is no longer good enough, move past 'make'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this Makefile

```
CC          = gcc
CFLAGS      = -Wall -Wextra -ansi
MD          = mkdir
BINPREFIX   = ../build
BUILD_DIR   = $(BINPREFIX)/$(shell basename $(CURDIR))
SRCS        = $(wildcard *.c)
BINS        = $(patsubst %.c,$(BUILD_DIR)/%,$(SRCS))

all: $(BINS)

$(BUILD_DIR):
    $(MD) -p $(BUILD_DIR)

$(BINS): $(BUILD_DIR)/%: %.c | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

So first I make a set of targets out of all c files in the current dir, prepending them with the `bin` directory I want to put all binaries. And then `$(BUILD_DIR)/%: %.c` performs the opposite manipulation - converts every target to the source file name.

Comment: You _really_ should be using simply-expanded variables (`:=`) for at least the wildcard, and probably also `BINS`.  Also why are you invoking a shell function instead of using the built-in `notdir` variable?  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html

Comment: Because I am Jon Snow in regards of Makefile variables :) thanks